# String concatenation for "undefined" variable with space in Javascript

Tags: javascript, casting, boolean, operators

I am trying to display a name and I am finding it difficult to concatenate undefined strings.

I want to display `displayName` if it's present or concatenate `firstName` and `lastName` and display it or go to `defaultName` if it's not present.

If my variables are present

```
let displayName = "John Doe";
let firstName = "Super";
let lastName = "Man";
let defaultName = "NIL";

console.log(displayName || firstName + " " + lastName || defaultName);

Output: John Doe
```

If variables are `undefined`

```js
    let displayName = undefined;
    let firstName = undefined;
    let lastName = undefined;
    let defaultName = "NIL";
    
    console.log(displayName || firstName + " " + lastName || defaultName);
```

```
Output: undefined undefined
```

It works when there is no `whitespace` as it treats it like an `arithmetic operator` but the output will be `SuperMan` due to lack of `whitespace`.

How do I solve it?

Comment: order of operations, use parenthesis. But I think you are going to have to change the logic....

Comment: Nope, not order order of operations. peinearydevelopment gave correct answer

Comment: You should probably use if and else, and break into multiple lines

Comment: `console.log(displayName || ((firstName || '') + ' ' + (lastName || '')).trim() || defaultName);` solves this entirely by taking advantage of type casting as well as of truthy and falsy values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... respect [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) and take advantage of [type casting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Type_Conversion) as well as of [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) and [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values ...

```js
let displayName;
let firstName;
let lastName;
let defaultName = 'NIL';

console.log(
     displayName
  || ((firstName || '') + ' ' + (lastName || '')).trim()
  || defaultName
);

displayName = '';
firstName = 'John';

console.log(
     displayName
  || ((firstName || '') + ' ' + (lastName || '')).trim()
  || defaultName
);

displayName = '';
firstName = '';
lastName = 'Doe';

console.log(
     displayName
  || ((firstName || '') + ' ' + (lastName || '')).trim()
  || defaultName
);

displayName = '';
firstName = 'John';

console.log(
     displayName
  || ((firstName || '') + ' ' + (lastName || '')).trim()
  || defaultName
);

displayName = '';
firstName = '';
lastName = '';

console.log(
     displayName
  || ((firstName || '') + ' ' + (lastName || '')).trim()
  || defaultName
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 4):

This assumes that only if firstName and lastName both have values, you want the second option to display otherwise show the defaultName

```js
let displayName = undefined;
let firstName = undefined;
let lastName = undefined;
let defaultName = "NIL";
console.log(displayName ? displayName : firstName && lastName ? `${firstName} ${lastName}` : defaultName);
```

Your `firstName + " " + lastName` as coded is always going to return a value which in JavaScript will have it evaluate to true which is the cause for what you are currently seeing.

Answer (score 1):

Queue jokes about 'foo' + + 'foo'.

A || B in javascript really means "If A is truthy, pass A. Otherwise, pass B". And types are out the window, Javascript will attempt to concatenate to a fault. Final wrench in the system is weird order of operation.

```
displayName || firstName   +  " "  + lastName  || defaultName
(displayName || firstName) + ((" " + lastName) || defaultName)
(        undefined       ) + (" undefined"     || defaultName)
         undefined         + " undefined"
"undefined undefined"
```

If you want to do this right, you have a bunch of good alternative options. I'd say something like

```
function forceGoodString(input) {
    if (typeof input === "string" && input.length) {
        return input;
    }   else    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

...I'm not actually sure what you expect with three undefined variables, " NIL" or just "NIL"? In any event, you need a few more lines. Nothing wrong with readability, not everything has to be fancy fancy `${garbage}` and ternary one liners.

```
if (displayName) {
    console.log(displayName);
}   else if (firstName && lastName) {
    console.log(firstName + " " + lastName);
}   else    {
    console.log(defaultName);
}
```

And if you ever get sick of the loose types in JS, you could always learn go!